# Error: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1

Tags: android, c++, opencv, mat

I am calling C++ function gives me this error: `signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1`
The crash dump is:

```
Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:6.0/MRA58K/2256973:user/release-keys'
pid: 19580, tid: 19706, name: Thread-6405  >>> com.adhamenaya <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xfa0
Stack frame 10-21 19:25:04.423   200   200 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 0041c59e  /data/app/com.adhamenaya-2/lib/arm/libGrafty.so (cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::_Outp
utArray const&) const+173): Routine cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::_OutputArray const&) const at ??:?
Stack frame 10-21 19:25:04.423   200   200 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0023b034  /data/app/com.adhamenaya-2/lib/arm/libGrafty.so (cv::Mat::clone() const+56
): Routine cv::Mat::clone() const at D:/scryptech/ndk_project/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:628 (discriminator 1)

Stack frame 10-21 19:25:04.423   200   200 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0023b3a4  /data/app/com.adhamenaya-2/lib/arm/libGrafty.so (GraftySystem::setCurrentF
rame(cv::Mat&)+44): Routine GraftySystem::setCurrentFrame(cv::Mat&) at C:\Users\aenaya\git\GraftyAndroid\GraftyAndroid/jni/grafty-system-settings.cpp:
39
Stack frame 10-21 19:25:04.423   200   200 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 002b339c  /data/app/com.adhamenaya-2/lib/arm/libGrafty.so (Java_com_adhamenaya_Nativ
e_runGrafty+492): Routine Java_com_adhamenaya_Native_runGrafty at C:\Users\aenaya\git\GraftyAndroid\GraftyAndroid/jni/grafty-hr-main.cpp:96 (discrimin
ator 1)
Stack frame 10-21 19:25:04.423   200   200 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 0036a627  /data/app/com.adhamenaya-2/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x29c000) (byte[] com
.adhamenaya.Native.runGrafty(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Long)+170)
Stack frame 10-21 19:25:04.423   200   200 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00369f33  /data/app/com.adhamenaya-2/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x29c000) (void com.a
dhamenaya.MainActivity$2.run()+574)
Stack frame 10-21 19:25:04.424   200   200 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 729298d1  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x1eb1000)
```

where:
**grafty-hr-main.cpp:96**

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_adhamenaya_Native_runGrafty(JNIEnv * env,
        jobject obj, jstring faceCascadeFile, jstring noseCascadeFile,
        jstring landmarks, jlong frame) {

    cv::Mat& inFrame = *(cv::Mat*) frame;


line 96 >>>>    gsys.setCurrentFrame(inFrame);
```

and:

**grafty-system-settings.cpp:39**

```
void GraftySystem::setCurrentFrame(cv::Mat& inFrame) {
    cv::Size2d imgRes;
    float resRatio;
line 39 >>>>>   cv::Mat frame = inFrame.clone();

}
```

and the call of the JNI function :

```
Java_com_adhamenaya_Native_runGrafty
```

is like this :

```
private Mat mGray;

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
        if (mRgba.empty())
            return null;
        else if (mRgba.channels() > 1)
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
        else
            mGray = mRgba;

        return mRgba;
    }
...
...
result = Native.runGrafty(mFaceCascadeFile,
                        mNoseCascadeFile, mLandmarks,
                        mGray.getNativeObjAddr());
```

It seems the problem in the frame parameter. Can you please help me in figuring out what is the problem ?

Comment: Are you sure casting an object of `jlong` to a pointer is alright?

Comment: jlong is the address of the native object(as passed from java). is not that right ?

Comment: @cad Do you see any error in that ? can you suggest something about it ?

Comment: Maybe the object the reference in the function at some point goes out of scope, resulting in undefined behavior (and possible a segfault), but that's just a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mGray = inputFrame.gray()
    return inputFrame.rgba();
}
```

OpenCV handles the conversion for you. What happens if you call the JNI code directly in the onCameraFrame() callback?